# Why can't I install FreePascal and the Gold linker at the same time?

Tags: package-management, haskell

I develop in Haskell privatly, but for school I have to use Delphi (I am allowed to use Lazarus though). To speed up linking in GHC (The compiler for Haskell) I installed `binutilus-gold`. But now, when I try to install `lazarus`, I get a conflicting package: `binutils-gold`. Does anybody knows, how to install both at the same time?

Comment: Spoke with a mod.  The tags you've requested are not needed, and as such will not be created.  However, [tag:binutils], I will create.

Comment: A great question. Could you quote the precise error message you get?

Comment: @Stefano Apt-get informs me, that the other package will be removed when I install one of them. That is all. No error.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we have that:

- lazarus     depends   on lazarus-ide
- lazarus-ide depends   on fp-compiler
- fp-compiler conflicts with binutils-gold

so I suggest to remove binutils-gold and stay with binutils.

Comment: Thank you, but I already know that this is an option. I rather want to know, how I could keep both packages.

Comment: I do not think there are other options if you would to stay in the same environment, without hacking the package manager. Separating the environments, for example with a chroot, it is possible, but that is probably overkill.

Comment: I wonder whether it is possible to use something like `update-alternatives` to symlink `ld` to the standard `ld` while keeping gold as `ld.gold` or something. i wonder whether it would be safe to knock out the conflict then.

Comment: @FUZxxl: if the package mantainers have established they conflict there should be serious arguments. I would not try and break an installation for that, but you're free to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Ubuntu package policies, but the search for "ld" of Free Pascal can be overriden using the -XP parameter.

The -XP parameter specifies a prefix that prefixes all calls to binutils with this prefix, and can be added to FPC's fpc.cfg to make it a default.

If you want to have the gold utils default, just create symlinks to say binutils-ld binutils-as binutils-ar etc somewhere in the $PATH and add

```
-XPbinutils-
```

on an empty line to /etc/fpc.cfg (some debian and ubuntu versions have a /etc/fpc.d hierarchy for FPC configs)